# HTML5 canvas javascript problems in delay

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying to make a delay while the graph was being drawn, but I think I am having trouble with `setTimeout`. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
function vertix(y,ctx){

  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(500, y);
}
function horizons(x,ctx){
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, 375);
}
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var context=ctx;
var i;
ctx.fillStyle='#FF0000';
canvas.setAttribute('align', 'center');
canvas.setAttribute('width', '800px');
canvas.setAttribute('height', '800px'); // clears the canvas

for (var x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
    setTimeout("horizons(x,ctx)",1000,'JavaScript');
}
for (var y = 0.5; y < 375; y += 10) {
    setTimeout("vertix(y,ctx)",1000,'JavaScript');
}
ctx.strokeStyle = "#eee";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 40);
ctx.lineTo(240, 40);
ctx.moveTo(260, 40);
ctx.lineTo(500, 40);
ctx.moveTo(495, 35);
ctx.lineTo(500, 40);
ctx.lineTo(495, 45);
ctx.moveTo(60, 0);
ctx.lineTo(60, 153);
ctx.moveTo(60, 173);
ctx.lineTo(60, 375);
ctx.moveTo(65, 370);
ctx.lineTo(60, 375);
ctx.lineTo(55, 370);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
ctx.stroke();
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
context.fillText("y", 58, 165);
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
context.fillText("y", 58, 165);
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.fillText("( 0 , 0 )", 8, 5);
context.textAlign = "right";
context.textBaseline = "bottom";
context.fillText("( 500 , 375 )", 492, 370);
context.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
context.fillRect(497, 372, 3, 3);

context.font = " 'TangerineRegular'";
context.fillText("Graph", 500, 400);
</script>
```

Comment: Use global context variable directly from function not pass it to parameter, also try to setTimeout like this: **setTimeout("horizons("+x+")", 1000, 'JavaScript')**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two fundamental problems:

1. Using string-based timeout handlers won't work because your `x` and `y` (and `ctx`) parameters aren't in scope
2. `setTimeout` doesn't delay the execution of everything after it, it just means "do *this* at some time in the future, meanwhile keep on going".

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/tGv4x/ which shows how this could be fixed.  The core of it is:

```
var hor_x = 0.5;
var vert_y = 0.5;
var delay = 100;

function vertix() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, vert_y);
    ctx.lineTo(500, vert_y);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (vert_y < 375) {
        vert_y += 10;
        setTimeout(vertix, delay);
    }
}

function horizons() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(hor_x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(hor_x, 375);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (hor_x < 500) {
        hor_x += 10;
        setTimeout(horizons, delay);
    } else {
        setTimeout(vertix, delay);
    }
}

horizons();
```

In essence - call a single function (`horizons`) which repeatedly triggers itself, using an externally scoped variable to store the current coordinates.  Once that one has finished, it hands over control to another function (`vertix`) which does the same thing for the other axis.

Comment: is there any delay function or technique in javascript?

Comment: @engr.waqas no - blocking the event queue is bad practise because it makes the browser unresponsive.  I just posted a fully working solution for you.

Comment: Thanks alot @Alnitak,i am just embeding it

Comment: Grid line are not behind the X,Y line. Graph is not like that !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this its working:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var context=ctx;
var i;

function vertix(y){
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(500, y);
}
function horizons(x){
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, 375);
}


ctx.fillStyle='#FF0000';
canvas.setAttribute('align', 'center');
canvas.setAttribute('width', '800px');
canvas.setAttribute('height', '800px'); // clears the canvas

for (var x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {        
 horizons(x)
}
for (var y = 0.5; y < 375; y += 10) {
 vertix(y)
}

ctx.strokeStyle = "#eee";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 40);
ctx.lineTo(240, 40);
ctx.moveTo(260, 40);
ctx.lineTo(500, 40);
ctx.moveTo(495, 35);
ctx.lineTo(500, 40);
ctx.lineTo(495, 45);
ctx.moveTo(60, 0);
ctx.lineTo(60, 153);
ctx.moveTo(60, 173);
ctx.lineTo(60, 375);
ctx.moveTo(65, 370);
ctx.lineTo(60, 375);
ctx.lineTo(55, 370);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
ctx.stroke();
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
context.fillText("y", 58, 165);
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
context.fillText("y", 58, 165);
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.fillText("( 0 , 0 )", 8, 5);
context.textAlign = "right";
context.textBaseline = "bottom";
context.fillText("( 500 , 375 )", 492, 370);
context.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
context.fillRect(497, 372, 3, 3);

context.font = " 'TangerineRegular'";
context.fillText("Graph", 500, 400);

</script>
```

Comment: the point was that he wants the grid to appear _gradually_.  This code will make it all appear at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var hor_x = 0.5;
var vert_y = 0.5;
var delay = 100;
function vertix() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, vert_y);
    ctx.lineTo(500, vert_y);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (vert_y < 375) {
        vert_y += 10;
        setTimeout(vertix, delay);
    }
}

function horizons() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(hor_x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(hor_x, 375);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (hor_x < 500) {
        hor_x += 10;
        setTimeout(horizons, delay);
    } else {
        setTimeout(vertix, delay);
    }
}
/*
function vertix(y,ctx){

  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(500, y);
}
function horizons(x,ctx){
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, 375);
}*/
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var context=ctx;
var i;
ctx.fillStyle='#FF0000';
canvas.setAttribute('align', 'center');
canvas.setAttribute('width', '800px');
canvas.setAttribute('height', '800px'); // clears the canvas
horizons();
vertix();
/*
for (var x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
    setTimeout("horizons(x,ctx)",1000,'JavaScript');
}
for (var y = 0.5; y < 375; y += 10) {
    setTimeout("vertix(y,ctx)",1000,'JavaScript');
}*/
ctx.strokeStyle = "#eee";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 40);
ctx.lineTo(240, 40);
ctx.moveTo(260, 40);
ctx.lineTo(500, 40);
ctx.moveTo(495, 35);
ctx.lineTo(500, 40);
ctx.lineTo(495, 45);
ctx.moveTo(60, 0);
ctx.lineTo(60, 153);
ctx.moveTo(60, 173);
ctx.lineTo(60, 375);
ctx.moveTo(65, 370);
ctx.lineTo(60, 375);
ctx.lineTo(55, 370);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
ctx.stroke();
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
context.fillText("y", 58, 165);
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
context.fillText("y", 58, 165);
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.fillText("( 0 , 0 )", 8, 5);
context.textAlign = "right";
context.textBaseline = "bottom";
context.fillText("( 500 , 375 )", 492, 370);
context.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
context.fillRect(497, 372, 3, 3);

context.font = " 'TangerineRegular'";
context.fillText("Graph", 500, 400);
</script>
```

its done upto the extent i wanted